# If I write a label without goto statement in my program what will happen?

Tags: c, error-handling, label, goto

If I write a label without using a `goto` statement, then the program runs in the program's flow. Why doesn't the compiler throw an error for the label?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int print(int a);

main()
{
    int a = 7;
hhh:
    print(a);
    if (a == 0)
        return;
    else
        --a;
    return;
}

int print(int a)
{
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Comment: See https://godbolt.org/z/h6rurG

Comment: Why would it? If you declare a variable or function and do not use it there's no error, why would this be different?

Comment: The compiler will probably warn about an unused label, but unless you tell it to treat all warnings as errors (which is actually a good practice), it will compile OK.  It isn't formally an error — unlike `goto non_existent;` where there is no label `non_existent` in the function — but it isn't a good idea to keep the unused label.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to add a label. Are you try to document something using a meaningful label ?

Answer (score 1):

You can define as many unused labels, variables, functions as you like. Unless you tell your compiler to use the highest possible warning level and to treat all warnings as errors, it will compile just fine.

Syntactically it's not an error to have unused stuff; it's commonly just bad style.

Answer (score 0):

Since the compiler cannot know if there is a logic error in that, it will not raise an error, it might give you a warning tough. But haveing a lavel does not break your code so it should be allowed to compile and run without any issues.